# Altering the FFT content

Tags: algorithm, matlab, fft

Suppose you have some data that is a tone plus noise.

```
t=0:0.01:10;
y=sin(t) + rand(1,length(t));
```

I am trying to knock down the tone peaks in the fft so that doing the ifft will result with just the noise data.  My algorithm would be a for loop that loops through each index of the abs(fft) to look for a peak.  If there is a peak, I would substitute that peak with a noisy datapoint instead.

Problem is, after the fft is done, in order to visualize the data, normally I would use plot(abs(fft)).  However, to do ifft, the imaginary data is also needed. Thus, I'm not sure how exactly I would go about "knocking the peak down" or getting rid of it so that I can use the ifft function.  I think I would have to work with the imaginary numbers.

Any suggestions? :X

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - That's a smart answer!  However, I want to expand this problem later so that random tones can be eliminated so I won't know what the cutoff frequency is.

Comment: A high pass filter isn't appropriate here because the noise is (theoretically) wideband - he'd be knocking down the noise as well as the signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to work with imaginary numbers, but I don't see why that's a problem. You can still look for the peaks using the magnitude (`abs`) representation, but when you "knock them down" you will put in place another complex value. It's up to you how you want to determine what this value should be - you could set it to zero, interpolate local frequencies, insert a random number...

Edit re: your comment:

Don't let imaginary numbers confuse you. They're not really "imaginary" anyway! It's just that to represent a sine wave at a given frequency, you need two values: magnitude and phase. Magnitude is what you're used to looking at and it determines *how much* of a given frequency we have. Phase determines the *shift* relative to some point (e.g. t = 0), which is also very important. As an example take the FFT to signals (say a sine and a cosine wave) with the same frequency - the magnitudes will look the same, but the phase will be different! If we didn't have phase, IFFT wouldn't know whether to give us a sine wave or a cosine wave, or something in between.

Of course, magnitude and phase are not the same thing as real and imaginary, but there is a simple formula to convert them. Either way we're using two numbers to represent each frequency.

Comment: Oh!  Yep, that is true.  Imaginary numbers confuse me! @_@  Thanks.  This should work out.

Comment: @stefan I'm sure I over-simplified, but can you expand: in what way is the amplitude not relevant?

Comment: @aganders3 my comment was a bit stupid written agreed. however, discussing the phase but not the frequency when we discuss a fft is a bit weak ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could look for "peaks" in the `abs(fft(y))` signal and replace them with random complex values by looking at the variance of the fft itself, something like

```
h = fft(y);

peaks = your_peak_finding_algorithm(abs(fft(y)));

real_noise = std(real(h));
imag_noise = std(imag(h));

h(peaks) = real_noise*randn(size(peaks)) + i*imag_noise*randn(size(peaks))

y_new = ifft(h);
```

**However**, I strongly question if this is really what you want to do.  If this is an academic exercise, then fine, but if it's for any kind of real application then I'd advise doing some research.  There's a *ton* of literature out there on noise reduction as well as detecting and filtering out tones in signals.

**Also Note** There is more information in the `fft` than just a single peak point related to your sinusoid.  See [Window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).  It depends on the sampling of your signal compared to its bandwidth, as well as the properties of the noise.